# Check the viability of a conversion function

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

I have the following code:

```
struct S {
  operator int();       // F1
   operator double();   // F2
};

int main() {
    int res = S();
}
```

Since neither `F1` nor `F2` is cv-qualified, the type of the implicit object parameter is `S&`, and the corresponding argument to be matched against is `S()`.

Now, per [[over.match.viable]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#viable-4): (**emphasis mine**)

> Third, for F to be a viable function, there shall exist for each
> argument an implicit conversion sequence that converts that argument
> to the corresponding parameter of F. **If the parameter has reference
> type, the implicit conversion sequence includes the operation of
> binding the reference, and the fact that an lvalue reference to
> non-const cannot bind to an rvalue and that an rvalue reference cannot
> bind to an lvalue can affect the viability of the function** (see
> [over.ics.ref]).

According to the above quote (bold), I'm expecting that neither `F1` nor `F2` is viable, because the implicit object parameter for both is of type `S&` and it cannot bind to an rvalue, `S()`.

But, when I tried to compile the code, I found out both functions are viable candidates. Which is best match is not what I am asking about here.

So, why are both `F1` and `F2` viable candidates, even though the implicit object parameter (of type `S&`) cannot bind to class prvalue `S()`?

Comment: @Morise Those conversion functions are *no overloads*! They are clearly distinguishable by their name, and you can call them explicitly that way. They have only one single (implicit) parameter and the only way you could overload them would be by having `const` and non-`const` overloads.

Comment: @Aconcagua - Anyway, you're correct. Can you answer/explain the question? `So why F1 and F2 both are viable candidates even though the implicit object parameter (of type S&) cannot bind to class prvalue S()?`

Comment: For overloads see @[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dfhecj5x1). The implicit parameter is yet another matter – considering the fact that `this` is a pointer the implicit parameter's type might be of type `S*` as well (whichever, as soon as compiled pointers and references, when parameters, don't differ one from another any more anyway apart from being reflected in name mangling...). We'd need to look up member function call now to be on the safe side – and we there we might find some exception to these binding rules, too. Though I'll be leaving that to you ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua - You still didn't give me an answer. I expect that F1 and F2 are not viable because I'm assuming (maybe incorrect) that the type of the implicit parameter is `S&` and its corresponding argument is S() (prvalue). Now per the quoted paragraph: _"the fact that an lvalue reference to non-const cannot bind to an rvalue and that an rvalue reference cannot bind to an lvalue can affect the viability of the function"_ Then F1 and F2 are not viables. This is my confusion basically; why they're viables?

Comment: @Morise The sole meaningful way out of the dilemma is, in my eyes, that *'parameter'* in the cited paragraph refers only to *explicit* parameters while the handling for the implicit one is described elsewhere. Otherwise *any* code like `struct S { void f() { } }; void g() { S().f(); }`, i.e. calling a member function on a temporary, would get just as invalid. As mentioned, you should look up *member function* call for to clarify.

Comment: By the way: *'or it is of type \*this'* – not *or* – both! `*this` *is* the implicit parameter... You have a member function, and when called, it is called with an additional, invisible parameter, namely the object on which you call the member function. `this` is the language's way to give you access to that implicit paremeter, such like the compiler turning `f` within `struct S { void f() { } };` into something equivalent to `void m_f(S* this) { }` (including some name mangling to be able to distinguish it from a non-member overload of same name with identical parameters).

Comment: @Aconcagua - I think this is the answer to my question as Adrian said: _"From over.match.funcs.general §5: ... For implicit object member functions declared without a ref-qualifier, even if the implicit object parameter is not const-qualified, an rvalue can be bound to the parameter [..]"_ Correct?

Comment: @Morise Looks pretty much so ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua - "_Those conversion functions are no overloads!_" This seems a new something to me. Can you tell me why those conversion functions are not overloads? because they differ only in the return type?

Comment: @Aconcagua - _"Those conversion functions are no overloads!"_ No, they're overloads. You can overload conversion functions normally. Check the example in the standard [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#general-example-1).

Comment: @Morise: Pretty simple: You can identify them by their unique name, and you can *call* them that way, too: `S s; s.operator int(); s.operator double();` Overloaded functions are identified by equal names and differing parameters – being those implicit or not...

Comment: @John And where in that example are those operators named as overloads of one another? The context is different, the example just illustrates comparison of conversion sequences.

Comment: @Morise Oh, and for completeness: You can add reference types to produce overloads for the object being a l- or r-value reference (since C++11): `struct S { void f() &; void f()&&; };` – so in combination with const-ness you could produce a total of four different overloads, though in general the const r-value reference overload would be pretty meaningless...

Comment: It seems to me that @AdrianMole already gave the correct answer, and should have actually posted it as an answer so that anyone who disagrees with it could comment under it. I have no idea what this thread is discussing now.

Comment: @Aconcagua: Overload resolution is not limited to sets of functions that we call “overloaded”; consider surrogate function calls and `operator()`, for example.  Or just functions brought into relevance by `using`.

Comment: @Aconcagua: The point is that overload resolution applies to them just as well as to multiple declarations of `f`; their distinct names are irrelevant (once they’ve been chosen by [over.match.funcs.general]/7).

Comment: @Aconcagua - I don't know why you still convinced that conversion operators cannot be overloaded even though you can have in a class something like `operator int()` and `operator int() const` or `operator int() &&` etc. All of those are overloaded conversion functions.

Comment: @John That's not what I'm saying! They *can* be overloaded, and I even demonstrated. But conversion operators for *different types* are not overloads. They can be distinguished not only by parameters, but already by their name, in contrast to [standard's definition](https://eel.is/c++draft/over#pre-1).

Comment: The interesting fact about is that functions can participate in overload resolution even if they actually are *not* overloads in the sense of above definition. They are simply part of the set of candidate functions...

Comment: @BrianBi OK, you've convinced me. But I have to admit that I have *some* reservations about the applicability of that section of the Standard in this case.

Comment: @Aconcagua - "_But conversion operators for different types are not overloads._". You're right. Sorry, after all, I think that I misunderstood your wording in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *main* concern expressed in your question appears to be how a *given* **rvalue** argument can bind to an *implicitly declared* **lvalue reference** parameter. (I'm not here even attempting to make an adjudication on the extensive discusssion in the comments to your question about whether or not any actual overloads are involved in your code sample.)

This (main) concern is addressed – quite clearly, IMHO – in another part of the **[over.match.funcs]** section of the [C++ Standard you cite](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs) (bold emphasis mine):

> ##### 12.2.2.1       General[over.match.funcs.general]
>
> …
> <sup>5</sup>     During overload resolution, the implied
> object argument is indistinguishable from other arguments. The implicit
> object parameter, however, retains its identity since no user-defined
> conversions can be applied to achieve a type match with it. For
> implicit object member functions declared without a ref-qualifier,
> even if the implicit object parameter is not const-qualified, ***an
> rvalue can be bound to the parameter as long as in all other respects
> the argument can be converted to the type of the implicit object
> parameter.***

Without this paragraph, implicit conversion functions would lose a great deal of their usefulness, such as the use-case you have provided in your example.

Comment: Can you demonstrate for me what's meant by _".. as long as in all other respects the argument can be converted to the type of the implicit object parameter."_

Comment: @John Presumably, if there is an implicit conversion provided, either by the language itself or by the code defining the type(s).

Comment: I guess that *could* be a question in its own right. But I'm not sure it would be very useful: I take it simply and basically meaning that there is nothing else preventing the required type conversion. In the OP's case, there would be nothing preventing the conversion from an `S` to another `S`.